# Conducting a power analysis on difference between two proportions

Tags: statistical-power

Suppose I have two (possibly biased) coins. I've run an experiment where I flipped each coin `N` times, and the coins landed heads with proportions `p_1 < p_2`.

Now I want to do a power analysis to figure out how many flips I need to run in a second experiment, in order to have an 80% chance of detecting a difference at least as great as what I've seen (i.e., detecting that the new `p_2 - p_1` is greater than or equal to the old `p_2 - p_1` -- I do want to that the second coin is more likely to land heads than the first coin, not just that the head probabilities are different) with significance 0.01. How do I do this? I'm unsure on both the theory and the particular method in R I would run.

I was thinking that the following R call would do the trick

```
library(pwr)
pwr.t.test(d = (p_2 - p_1) / sqrt(p_1 * (1 - p_1)), sig.level = 0.01, power = 0.8, alternative = "greater")
```

But I'm not sure my `d = (p_2 - p_1) / sqrt(p_1 * (1 - p_1))` is correct (in particular, I'm not sure if my denominator is correct, or what I should put there instead).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are power calculation functions specifically for proportions such as `power.prop.test`:

```
> power.prop.test(p1=0.4, p2=0.6, power=0.8)

     Two-sample comparison of proportions power calculation 

              n = 96.92364
             p1 = 0.4
             p2 = 0.6
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.8
    alternative = two.sided

 NOTE: n is number in *each* group
```

Comment: In the pwr package, also pwr.2p.test and pwr.2p2n.test.